# Trouble with Lambda in Scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme

> This question stores information about taxpayers and how their taxes
>   are calculated. A new type Taxpayer is required: ;; A Taxpayer is a
>   structure (make-taxpayer inc c), where ;; inc is a non-negative number
>   (the taxpayer's income), and ;; c is a function (Num -> Num) that
>   consumes an nonnegative ;; income and produces the nonnegative amount
>   of taxes ;; owed on that income (define-struct taxpayer (income
>   calculation)) Write a Scheme function average-taxes that consumes a
>   list of Taxpayer structures, called lotp, and produces the average
>   amount of taxes owed for all taxpayers in lotp. If lotp is empty, then
>   0 is produced. For example, using functions corresponding to current
>   federal tax rates, (average-taxes (list (make-taxpayer 70000 (lambda
>   (a) (+ 6593 (* 0.22 (- a 43953))))) (make-taxpayer 0 (lambda (a) (*
>   0.15 a))) (make-taxpayer 140000 (lambda (a) (+ 28837 (* 0.29 (- a 136270)))))))
>   => 14080.68

I am trying to solve the above problem ... Below is my attempt:

```
(define-struct taxpayer (income calculation))

(define (average-taxes lotp)
  (/
   (foldr + 0
         (map (lambda (t) ((taxpayer-calculation t) taxpayer-income t)) lotp))
    (length lotp)))
I get the following error when running this test:

    (define mylist
      (list
    (make-taxpayer 70000 (lambda (a) (+ 6593 (* 0.22 (- a 43953)))))
    (make-taxpayer 0 (lambda (a) (* 0.15 a)))
    (make-taxpayer 140000 (lambda (a) (+ 28837
    (* 0.29 (- a 136270)))))))

    (average-taxes mylist) =>

    ... 2 Quesion 4.rkt:11:21: expects only 1 argument, but found 2
```

Any advice as to why the error is happening and what approaches I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo; `taxpayer-income` is a procedure so you need to say `(taxpayer-income t)`:

```
(define (average-taxes lotp)
  (/ 
   (foldr + 0
          (map (lambda (t) ((taxpayer-calculation t) (taxpayer-income t))) lotp))
   (length lotp)))
```